# Textarea height based on placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to solve problem with textarea height if placeholder is showing. For text resizing I'm using: **monospaced/angular-elastic** which works fine.

My problem is with placeholders:

- [multi-line placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx60z.png)
- [one-lineplaceholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6lEz.png) - this should be 1 line, not 2

Is possible to adjust height of placeholder based on placeholder's height?

```
textarea {
          min-height: 18px;
          display: block;
          color: #4B565C;
          word-wrap: break-word;
          resize: none;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          display: block;
          line-height: 1.4;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<textarea 
       msd-elastic 
       ng-model="ng.model"
       ng-trim="false"
       ng-focus="ng.fnFocus()"
       ng-blur="ng.fnBlur()"
       ng-paste="ng.fnPaste($event)"
       ng-change="ng.fnChange()"
       placeholder="ng.placeholderText">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Show us your code, pictures don't help much to identify the problem

Comment: use text with keyup function instead of placeholder

Comment: We need to know how you set multi-line placeholders to offer your a solution. There's a few weird ones, but show us your code first.